# Lost the ability to view array contents in debug mode

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am a newbie to vb.net but have been learning fast as I work with it. When I first installed Vb studio 2015, I was able to see the contents of an array when mousing over the array variable while running the program. When moused over the array variable had a right pointing arrow on far left of pop up. It has now been replaced by a box like looking image and I can only see the current field value of an array rather than the whole thing. Clicking on the arrow would drop down a menu with all the array contents displayed. I'm pretty sure I did not change anything in the options area that may have disabled this feature.
Is there somewhere in options or another area that determines how debug mode will present array contents ???

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: have a look in the Locals window when you are debugging. You should be able to see the array contents there

Comment: I took a look for that window and cannot seem to find it under View drop down menu. I seem to remember seeing it before but it too seems to have vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just add a watch to the array (Right click > Add Watch) and view it in the Watch Window?

Comment: Yes, I have done that BUT before if the array was in the watch window that same little arrow head was present and I could expand to see the entire array contents. This has disappeared as well. I can only view the current array element selected. It's just too weird how it just lost this function.

Comment: Correction: I can see the arrowhead in the watch window and click it to expand and view entire Array contents. But I miss having the ability to just mouse over the array variable in the code window and see that arrowhead then click and expand it to view entire array just as in the watch window. Just too odd that it just went away for no clear reason.

Comment: I believe it is to do with the point in your code execution you are at. if the last thing you did was add something to the array you wont get the + sign to see the Array contents. If you want to test it, create a loop to add all the array contents to a string then hover over your array.

Answer (score 0):

in VB.net just put a pause near the array you want to see the values, click on the array name in the code and you get a drop down menu, you can see all the values from there